# Space after float with [h]

Tags: spacing, floats, captions, positioning

this is my first time here, and I have this question:

I'm writing my thesis, that includes many tables and figures in a `float` environment, with the caption at the end of it. I defined the space between the end of float's caption and the next paragraph. This works fine, but when I forced to stay when I tiped (with [h]), this space (between caption and next paragraph) is bigger. Of course, one of the items that will be evaluated, is the spaces (they all must be the same).

So, my question is: How can I solve this?

There is an example of the code I'm using: (TexShop —Mac Os 10.6.8)

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,12pt,oneside]{book}
\usepackage[spanish,es-lcroman]{babel}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[font=small,format=hang,parskip=1pt]{caption}
\usepackage{ctable}
\usepackage{float}
\raggedbottom
\begin{document}
\setlength{\textfloatsep}{10pt} 
\setlength{\abovecaptionskip}{10pt}
\setlength{\belowcaptionskip}{5pt}
...
\end{document}
```

---

[image]

Comment: I recommend not to use `[h]`. There's no guarantee that there's sufficient space at the page, so LaTeX itself would even change it to `[ht]`. You could use `[ht]` yourself, so that it goes to the next page if there's insufficient space left. Btw. if you really mean *here*, use `[H]`. It comes from the `float` package you already loaded.

Comment: If I use the `[H]`, the font's size is **bigger**!! But, the main problem is that the float w/out the `[h]`, goes to the top of the current page, not to the next; with the `[h]`, stays where I want, but with this bigger space under the caption. And in some cases, w/out the `[h]` the float goes under the `\footnote` (under the line and all the footnote's text). I don't now how to post a image of this to prove it!

Comment: If you don't specify anything for the float placement, then it defaults to `[tbp]`. So, LaTeX first attempt to put the float at the **top** of the page, then the **bottom**, then on a **page** of its own.

Comment: You're right! So, when the float is at the **top** by default (AND in the same page), the space is fine; but when I force it (`[h]`) or it floats to the next page, the space is bigger.

Comment: You can edit your question to provide more information. Please only use the official image uploader (e.g. CTRL+G). I reuploaded the image now and merged your post into the question. Thanks.

Answer (score 28):

Space below **top** `[t]` and above **bottom** `[b]` floats is managed via the length `\textfloatsep`. Space above and below **here** `[h]` floats is managed via the length `\intextsep`.

```
\setlength{\intextsep}{10pt} % Vertical space above & below [h] floats
\setlength{\textfloatsep}{10pt} % Vertical space below (above) [t] ([b]) floats
\setlength{\abovecaptionskip}{10pt}
\setlength{\belowcaptionskip}{5pt}
```

Chapter 6 of the [`layouts` package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/layouts) [documentation](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/layouts/layman.pdf) highlights some of the standard lengths/definitions employed by LaTeX when working with floats. Here's a snapshot of the graphic in question:

[image: Page layouts used by LaTeX]

Comment: Thanks, but `\intextsep` seems not to work for me!! I tried modifying the value, but I note no differences. Thank you anyway!!

Comment: I've added the graphic in question to show where `\intextsep` has an effect.