# How do I remove unnecessary spacing before and after a table?

Tags: tables, spacing

Example:

```
Let A = \{$\alpha$,$\beta$,$\psi$\} be a set operates on $\star$ then

\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{l|lll}
\textbf{$\star$} & \textbf{$\alpha$} & \textbf{$\beta$} &\textbf{$\gamma$}\\
\hline
$\alpha$ & $\alpha$ & $\alpha$ & $\alpha$ \\
$\beta$  & $\beta$  & $\beta$  & $\beta$  \\
$\gamma$ & $\gamma$ & $\gamma$ & $\gamma$ \\
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

Further text.
```

I want to remove unnecessary extra spacing before and after the table.

Comment: The answer is here: [How to change the spacing between figures/tables and text?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26521/how-to-change-the-spacing-between-figures-tables-and-text).

Comment: i want to use \centering only for the table. how to do it?

Comment: If you want to use `\centering` without `table` environment, use `\begin{center} ... \end{center}` or `minipage` instead.

Comment: See also "Changing lengths" at [SUED - Squeezing Space in LaTeX](http://www.eng.cam.ac.uk/help/tpl/textprocessing/squeeze.html).

Comment: @selwyndd21: `\begin{center} ... \end{center}` also adds space, so that's not the way to go.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

do not use a `table` environment if you do not need it:

```
 \documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

  \begin{enumerate}
    \item Set of an integer is closed under $+$ , $-$ , $\times$ operator.
    \item Set of an integer is not closed under $/$ operator.
  \end{enumerate}

Let A = \{$\alpha$,$\beta$,$\psi$\} is a set operates on $\star$ then

\begin{tabular}{l|lll}
\textbf{$\star$} & \textbf{$\alpha$} & \textbf{$\beta$} &\textbf{$\gamma$}\\
\hline
$\alpha$ & $\alpha$ &$\alpha$ &$\alpha$\\
$\beta$ & $\beta$ &$\beta$ &$\beta$\\
%\midrule
$\gamma$ & $\gamma$ &$\gamma$ &$\gamma$\\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

and if you want the tabular centered use:

```
{\centering
\begin{tabular}{l|lll}
\textbf{$\star$} & \textbf{$\alpha$} & \textbf{$\beta$} &\textbf{$\gamma$}\\
\hline
$\alpha$ & $\alpha$ &$\alpha$ &$\alpha$\\
$\beta$ & $\beta$ &$\beta$ &$\beta$\\
%\midrule
$\gamma$ & $\gamma$ &$\gamma$ &$\gamma$\\
\end{tabular}\par}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{l|lll}
...
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
```

rather than a `table` environment.

Comment: don't use a `center` environment unless you prefer _its_ spacing to that separating a float from surrounding text.

Comment: sry i didnt get u...we are beginner