# why sometimes the figure is too close to the text?

Tags: graphics

Here is the problem, you can see the figure is too close to the text, And it is even affecting the text.

[image]

the code I use is

```
\documentclass[ reprint,amsmath,amssymb,aps]{revtex4-1}
\usepackage{graphicx}% Include figure files
\usepackage{dcolumn}% Align table columns on decimal point
\usepackage{bm}% bold math
\usepackage{epstopdf}

\begin{document}
some text

\begin{figure}[htbp]
\includegraphics[width=\columnwidth]{FIG_3}
\end{figure}

some text
\end{document}
```

What is odd enough is that when I insert the same code between other paragraphs of my paper, the problem is not showing any more.

after add \fbox{} to show the bounding box as follows

[image]

---

**Edited**

***Here is the problematic tex file that I share on google drive*** [problematic tex file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0By4WA9GK6t9DQkRtWDRmN1BINUk/edit?usp=sharing)

---

**here is the example show that two same figure code but different position have different space to the text.**

[image]

Comment: That shouldn't happen, which means that there is a problem in some code you haven't shown us.

Comment: Bad bounding box for figure?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: @MartinSchröder Thank you for the welcome, I elaborated my question.

Comment: @jonalv well, I tried many eps figure (even borrowed from other people) inserted in that place, all oddly failed.

Comment: @user15964: Please add an `\fbox{}` around your `\includegraphics`. This will show the bounding box TeX sees. And please make your code a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228). And a suggestion: Do us a favour and change your username to something more telling than "user1234".

Comment: @MartinSchröder I add the \fbox{}

Comment: @MartinSchröder I share a problematic tex, see my edited question or here https://drive.google.com/file/d/0By4WA9GK6t9DQkRtWDRmN1BINUk/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [How to change the spacing between figures/tables and text?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26521/how-to-change-the-spacing-between-figures-tables-and-text)

An exaggerated example to play:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}

% for figure A between text
\setlength{\intextsep}{5em plus 1em minus .1em} 

% for the figure B on top (or bottom)
\setlength{\textfloatsep}{10em plus 5em minus .1em} % for figure B

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]

\begin{figure}[h]
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
\end{figure}
\lipsum[2]

\begin{figure}[t]
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-b}
\end{figure}

\lipsum[3-6]

\end{document}
```

**Edit**: the edited question now show a MWE with the problem in the `revtex4-1` class. For some reason I obtained some wrongs compilations using this MWE but I cannot explain why. This code work fine:

```
\documentclass[reprint,amsmath,amssymb,aps]{revtex4-1}
\usepackage{graphicx}% Include figure files
\usepackage{dcolumn}% Align table columns on decimal point
\usepackage{bm}% bold math
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\setlength{\intextsep}{2cm} 
\setlength{\textfloatsep}{2cm} 

\begin{document}

\lipsum[2]

\begin{figure}[h]
\includegraphics[width=\columnwidth]{example-image-a}
\end{figure}

\lipsum[2]

\begin{figure}[t]
\includegraphics[width=\columnwidth]{example-image-b}
\end{figure}

\lipsum[2]

\begin{figure}[b]
\includegraphics[width=\columnwidth]{example-image-c}
\end{figure}

\lipsum[3-6]

\end{document}
```

[image: MWE]

Comment: Thank you for your answer, Fran!  what does MWE mean?

Comment: I tried your method, it didn't work for that particular position. I really don't understand what kind of bug it is! I tried to progressively add text before this figure code, and only if I add enough text will the space become normal. Quite odd!

Comment: I look through a latex document, and that document said if I use [h], then the \intextsep is 12pt plus 2pt minus 2pt by default. So I think your method maybe not working for my problem.

Comment: @user15964 A MWE is a  [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates exactly your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: @user15964 Add to your question a MWE with example figures of the `mwe` package (so we can also compile the MWE without problem) and the enough dummy text to reproduce where `\intextsep` or another length is ignored.

Comment: see the problematic tex file https://drive.google.com/file/d/0By4WA9GK6t9DQkRtWDRmN1BINUk/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: @user1596 It seems a bug of `revtex4-1`. For some reason, `\intextsep` is ignored just  in this circumstances, but  usually it is recognized, so ...