# How to locally reduce the vertical space around a figure?

Tags: graphics, floats

How can I reduce the space below and above a figure? I found the following [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/26522/36374), describing how I can reduce the vertical spacing for floats globally. How can I achieve this locally (on a single page)? I'm also satisfied with a solution without the floating environment (but including centering), as the figure is placed on a title page and is not really supposed to float. Below what I'm using now.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,twoside]{book}
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{epstopdf}   
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[nopar]{lipsum}



\begin{document}

\noindent \footnotesize{\lipsum[4]\\
\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=3cm]{CC_logo.eps}
\end{figure}
\noindent \lipsum[4]


\end{document}
```

Comment: Firstly don't put the `\includegraphics` inside a `figure` environment. It's not necessary. If you want it centered, use `\begin{center}...\end{center}`. Minor vertical adjustments are possible by using `\vspace{<len>}` with a negative `<len>`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since the image must appear on a precise location, instead of a floating object, you can use a `minipage`. Using `\par\smallskip` (or `\medskip`, or even `\vspace{<length>}`), you can adjust the vertical spacing:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,twoside]{book}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx} 
\usepackage{epstopdf}   
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[nopar]{lipsum}

\begin{document}

{\footnotesize
\noindent 
\lipsum[4]\par\smallskip
\noindent
\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=3cm]{CC_logo.eps}
\end{minipage}\par\smallskip
\noindent\lipsum[4]\par}

\end{document}
```

[image]

As a side note, `\footnotesize` does not receive arguments; it is a font switch. You can limit its scope by grouping: `{\footnotesize text text...}`, or `{\footnotesize text text...\par}` if more than one line is involved.

An alternative, mentioned by **Werner** in his comment, is to use a `center` environment and `\vspace{<length>}` commands to fine tune the space:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,twoside]{book}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx} 
\usepackage{epstopdf}   
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[nopar]{lipsum}

\begin{document}

{
\footnotesize
\noindent 
\lipsum[4]

\vspace{-7pt}
\begin{center}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=3cm]{CC_logo.eps}
\end{center}
\vspace{-9pt}
\lipsum[4]\par
}

\end{document}
```

The `demo` option for `graphicx` simply replaces actual figures with black rectangles; do *not* use that option in your actual document.

Comment: In the first version the figure is not in the center but slightly shifted to the right. How can I change this?

Comment: @Tanja Sorry about that. I forgot a `\noindent`; now it is fixed.