# Fill page with text

Tags: vertical-alignment, luatex

With command `\raggedbottom` lines on pages are aligned. I need it, `\flushbottom` generate quite ugly book spread, but in result some pages have different height of text block. I tried play agound with "glue" `\spaceskip=\fontdimen2\font plus 5\fontdimen2\font minus 0.3pt` and `\emergencystretch = 2em`, but it don't have an effect on all book pages. Is there any good solution, or i need to check every page and play with glue there directly? `\defaultfontfeatures{Microtypography,Ligatures={TeX},Renderer=Basic}` have no effect too. [image: Example] MWE is:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{polyglossia}

\usepackage[hyphenation,parindent,lastparline,nosingleletter]{impnattypo}

\usepackage[defaultlines=2,all]{nowidow}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage[
    paperheight=215mm,
    paperwidth=145mm,
    top=2cm, 
    bottom=2.5cm,
    inner=2cm,
    outer=2cm
]{geometry}

\setmainlanguage{english}

\defaultfontfeatures{Microtypography,Ligatures={TeX},Renderer=Basic}

\protrudechars=2 % or \pdfprotrudechars=2 and
\adjustspacing=2 %    \pdfadjustspacing=2 with luatex < v0.85
\newfontfeature{Microtypography}{protrusion=default;expansion=default}
\directlua{fonts.protrusions.setups.default.factor=1}

\setmainfont{Arial}

\frenchspacing
\raggedbottom

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-150]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Search the .log file for all `Underfull \vbox` warnings and manually fix them in order. Operation to be done when the text is final. You can use \enlargethispage, \looseness and other "tricks" to get the best page fill

Comment: It is hard make accurate advices without see directly the problem and having to guess what you have not  told us about your document. With the  `lipsum` package and the images supplied by the `mwe` is a child play to reproduce any problem in a fake document that anybody can see and test for some  fix, and show you the exact result.

Comment: The only purpose of `\raggedbottom` is to allow the space that you have marked in red so if you don't want that then use `\flushbottom` you then need to control (or remove) other stretchy space on the page, see any questions/answers with [tag:grid-typesetting]

Comment: Yea, grid works... mostly same as \raggedbottom...
I need to align lines on pages, not in columns.

Comment: If you need to have matching baselines across pages, and simultaneously wish to avoid widow and club lines, you should look into adjusting susceptible paragraphs using `\looseness`.  See [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/318004) for ideas.  (By the way, I changed your tag "align" to "vertical alignment".  "align" is specific to a particular math structure.)

Comment: note you are forcing the bad break here with `\usepackage[defaultlines=2,all]{nowidow}` so tex can not add the extra  line, that is a very blunt instrament the more interactive controls of the `widows-and-orphans` package may be more suitable.

Comment: It would help testing answers if you posted an example that produced the image that you show (the image posted is clearly not using Arial and the test code produces 36 pages many of them are OK so not really an easy test case)

Answer (score 1):

The marked white space (or at least equivalent space in the test document)  at the bottom of the page was occuring as you were explicitly allowing it via the `\raggedbottom` declaration, and then forcing the break there by disallowing one line of the next paragraph to be placed on that page.

Using `\flushbottom` tells tex not to allow space in that position

Soecifying `heightrounded` to geometry ensures that it is possible to fit in continuos text and achieve the required bottom baseline, by forcing the text height is an integer multiple of `\baselineskip` plus `\topskip`.

Replacing the `no-widow` package by `widows-and-orphans` allows the pages to be filled but warns of widows and orphans in the log:

```
Package widows-and-orphans Warning: Orphan on page 6
Package widows-and-orphans Warning: Widow on page 13
Package widows-and-orphans Warning: Orphan on page 17
Package widows-and-orphans Warning: Widow on page 23
Package widows-and-orphans Warning: Orphan on page 31
Package widows-and-orphans Warning: Orphan on page 32
```

You can then adjust each in turn re-wording or using `\enlargethispage` or here I just used `\looseness` to force some paragraphs to take a line less or a line more than they would otherwise, resulting in 36 pages all full with no widows or orphans

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{polyglossia}

\usepackage[hyphenation,parindent,lastparline,nosingleletter]{impnattypo}

%\usepackage[defaultlines=2,all]{nowidow}
\usepackage{widows-and-orphans}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage[
    paperheight=215mm,
    paperwidth=145mm,
    top=2cm, 
    bottom=2.5cm,
    inner=2cm,
    outer=2cm,
    heightrounded
]{geometry}

\setmainlanguage{english}

\defaultfontfeatures{Microtypography,Ligatures={TeX},Renderer=Basic}

\protrudechars=2 % or \pdfprotrudechars=2 and
\adjustspacing=2 %    \pdfadjustspacing=2 with luatex < v0.85
\newfontfeature{Microtypography}{protrusion=default;expansion=default}
\directlua{fonts.protrusions.setups.default.factor=1}

\setmainfont{Arial}

\frenchspacing
\flushbottom

\begin{document}

% just so I can see which para is which
\everypar{\stepcounter{enumi}\makebox[0pt][r]{\theenumi\ }}

\lipsum[1-24]

\looseness=1
\lipsum[25]

\lipsum[26-32]

\looseness=1
\lipsum[33]

\lipsum[34-71]

\looseness=1
\lipsum[72]

\lipsum[73-77]

\looseness=1
\lipsum[78]

\lipsum[79-80]

\looseness=1
\lipsum[81]

\lipsum[82]

\lipsum[83]

\looseness=1
\lipsum[84]

\lipsum[85-108]

\looseness=-1
\lipsum[109]

\lipsum[110-128]

\looseness=1
\lipsum[129]

\lipsum[130-150]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for example, but. "flushed" space between paragraphs extremely ruin main requirement. Lines on book spread must be aligned. I mean baselines on odd page must be aligned with baselines on even page. \raggedbottom prevent play with glue between paragraphs, and gives me mostly what I need. \looseness and \spaceskip. looks nice, but I thought it too much "manualy" solution.

Comment: @Faktor sorry that is completely the wrong approach, `\raggedbottom` as its name implies is explicitly designed to produce the space that you ask to avoid. No inter paragraph spaces are stretched in this answer, if you want to make sure they never stretch then as I mentioned in a comment  under the question set them to a fixed length, `\setlength\parskip{0pt}` for example.

Comment: @Faktor if you do not change the linebreakig with looseness or change the wording or give up on widows your constraints are not attainable, you have solid text with no white space so the number of lines per page is fixed, if that happens to be the first line of a paragraph and you do not allow breaking there you need to make something on the page a line longer as I do here or allow the page to be short or allow a page break after the first line. TeX never changes the line breaking to adjust the page breaking so it needs manual control or a multi-pass system or ...

Comment: @Faktor -- `\looseness` really is the way to go here.  Unless you have a lot of 3-line paragraphs, judicious use of `\looseness` is your dependable friend.  Learn to use it well, and you'll never look back.