# Overwrite default distance between figure caption and text

Tags: floats, captions

I would like to set the distance between figure caption and text to be 24pt. Even though `\belowcaptionskip` is zero for report class, the following code produces a pdf where the distance between caption and text is non-zero. How can I overwrite default value of that distance?

[image]

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{mwe}
\pagenumbering{gobble}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \includegraphics{example-image-a}
    \caption{Some dummy caption.}
\end{figure}

\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

Comment: [How to change the spacing between figures/tables and text?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/26521/134144)  is closely related.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\belowcaptionskip` is the space *within* the float below a caption (for the cases when the caption is above the table), your image shows that (in this case) the figure ended up as the last float in a top float area, the space between that and the top of the following text is `\textfloatsep`