# Reducing space between 2 algorithms using algorithm2e

Tags: spacing, floats, algorithm2e

Is there any way to reduce the space between two algorithms?

Here is a screenshot:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[linesnumbered,ruled,vlined]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}
\label{alg:my-alg}
\DontPrintSemicolon
\caption{My algorithm}
\SetKwInOut{Input}{Input}\SetKwInOut{Output}{Output}
\Input{$a,b,...$}
\Output{$R$}
statment1\; 
statment2\;
statment3\;
\tikzmark{start}\lIf{$a>b$}{\KwRet{$a$\tikzmark{stop}}}\;
\KwRet{$b$}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
\draw[red,thick] ([yshift=0.5ex]pic cs:start) -- ([yshift=0.5ex]pic cs:stop);
\end{tikzpicture}%
\end{algorithm}
\begin{algorithm}
\label{alg:my-alg}
\DontPrintSemicolon
\caption{My algorithm}
\SetKwInOut{Input}{Input}\SetKwInOut{Output}{Output}
\Input{$a,b,...$}
\Output{$R$}
statment1\; 
statment2\;
statment3\;
\tikzmark{start}\lIf{$a>b$}{\KwRet{$a$\tikzmark{stop}}}\;
\KwRet{$b$}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
\draw[red,thick] ([yshift=0.5ex]pic cs:start) -- ([yshift=0.5ex]pic cs:stop);
\end{tikzpicture}%
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually when you place an `algorithm` it is treated as a float and the spacing between floats depend on a number of factors discussed in [How to change the spacing between figures/tables and text?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/26521/5764) However, in some cases it's convenient to have multiple floats move together (always). This is supported in the following way: Please all the `algorithm`s as non-floating blocks (using the `[H]` float specifier) inside another float (like `figure`).

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[ruled]{algorithm2e}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
  \begin{algorithm}[H]
    \caption{An algorithm}
    A step in the algorithm
  \end{algorithm}

  % Additional spacing can be inserted here (like \bigskip, for example)

  \begin{algorithm}[H]
    \caption{A different algorithm}
    Another step in this different algorithm
  \end{algorithm}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Additional spacing parameters can be inserted, depending on your personal taste.

Comment: It did work!!! I tried with `\begin{figure}` but it was throwing an error because `[H]` was missing. Thank you!