# How to reduce the space between figure* and text?

Tags: floats

I am trying to reduce the space between figure* and text. I tried out the method provided at [How to change the spacing between figures/tables and text?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26521/how-to-change-the-spacing-between-figures-tables-and-text), but it doesn't work. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Could you provide some more context in terms of "the solution not working"? Specifically, please provide a minimal example (that starts with `\documentclass` and ends with `\end{document}`) that shows why it's not working. Could you do that?

Comment: `\dbltextfloatsep` as shown in that answer is the only generic answer, so if it is not working please add a complete small document to your question so people can debug