# Empty space after adding an image

Tags: spacing, graphics

After adding an image I have an empty space. How can it be reduced? I used `\FloatBarrier`. But it did not worked.

```
% Following copied by Marc van Dongen from comment from OP.
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside]{report}
   \usepackage{fancyhdr}
   \usepackage{graphicx}
   \usepackage{placeins}
   \begin{document}
   \FloatBarrier
   \subsection{ddd}
      \begin{figure}[ht]
         \begin{center}
            \includegraphics[width=9cm,height=5.5cm]{sss.jpg}
         \end{center}
         \begin{center}
            \caption[ddd ]{ ddd }
         \end{center}
      \end{figure}
      \FloatBarrier
      In English, the word datum is still used in the general
       sense of "an item given".
      In cartography, geography, nuclear magnetic
\end{document}
```

Comment: I only used these packages,                           \usepackage[left=1.5in,top=1in,right=1in,bottom=5em]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{placeins}
\usepackage[font=bf,labelfont={sf,bf}]{caption}%Figure Caption Bold
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{sectsty}
\usepackage{titlesec}                                                                                                                      Actually I need to reduce the vertical empty space after the image.what i need to use for that?

Comment: Please post your complete and minimal code. Remove any unrelated packages.

Comment: \documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside]{report}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
 \usepackage{graphicx}
 \usepackage{placeins} 
\begin{document}
\FloatBarrier
\subsection{ddd}
\begin{figure}[ht]
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[width=9cm,height=5.5cm]{sss.jpg}
\end{center}
\begin{center}
\caption[ddd ]{ ddd }
\end{center}
\end{figure}
\FloatBarrier
In English, the word datum is still used in the general sense of "an item given". In cartography, geography, nuclear magnetic 
\end{document}

Comment: @emalka You're supposed to provide the MWE in your question. I've copied your MWE and pasted it in your question.

Answer (score 1):

Apart of  use of `\centering` of Werner answer, you can also control  the space below the  captions with `\belowcaptionskip` (for example `\belowcaptionskip-1em`) in the preamble or adjust manually a particular  space with a negative `\vspace` (for example `\vspace{-1cm}`) in the text under the float.

However, to obtain an elegant format, simply use `\centering`.

Comment: I need to only enhance the vertical space between two images....not  all images in the document.\vspace{-1cm} this reduce space.so what i need to do for enhance the space.\vspace{10cm} this not worked.

Answer (score 0):

You should avoid using the `center` environment to align your content. Specifically, use `\centering` to centre content within a floating environment like `figure`:

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside]{report}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\subsection{ddd}
\begin{figure}[ht]
  \begin{center}
    \includegraphics[width=9cm,height=5.5cm]{example-image-a}
  \end{center}
  \begin{center}
    \caption[ddd ]{ ddd }
  \end{center}
\end{figure}
In English, the word datum is still used in the general
 sense of ``an item given.''
In cartography, geography, nuclear magnetic.

\newpage

\subsection{ddd}
\begin{figure}[ht]
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=9cm,height=5.5cm]{example-image-a}
  \caption[ddd ]{ ddd }
\end{figure}
In English, the word datum is still used in the general
 sense of ``an item given.''
In cartography, geography, nuclear magnetic.
\end{document}
```

See [Should I use `center` or `\centering` for figures and tables?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/2651/5764).

Comment: It worked..thank u...                                                              I also need to create space between inserted two images.. \vspace{10.00mm}  is not worked.                                                                                                                       \begin{figure}[h!]
 \centering
..............
\end{figure}
\vspace{10.00mm}
\begin{figure}[h!]
 \centering
..............................
\end{figure}

Comment: @emalka: The space between floats and other floats (or other textual elements on a page) is governed by specific lengths. In your case it is `\floatsep`. So you could `\setlength{\floatsep}{10mm}`. For a more general discussion, see the [`layouts` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/layouts/layman.pdf) (section **6.2 Detailed float layout** and Figure 13), or [How to change the spacing between figures/tables and text?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/26521/5764) or [Space after float with `[h]`](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/24454/5764).