# Why here is a large gap between caption and next text? Can I fix it?

Tags: tables

[image: sample]

```
asasasasasasasasasasas

\begin{table}[ht] 
    \centering 
    \begin{tabular}{|r|l|}
        \hline
        7C0 & hexadecimal \\
        3700 & octal \\ \cline{2-2}
        11111000000 & binary \\
        \hline \hline
        1984 & decimal \\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \caption[You-table]{Table for you}
    \label{table: me} 
\end{table} 

Measuring AC heat capacity is an excellent radiation
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer is already [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26521/how-to-change-the-spacing-between-figures-tables-and-text) or [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24454/space-after-float-with-h/24468#24468). In a nutshell: There are several length registers such as `\textfloatsep`. You can change them by using `\setlength`.

Comment: Isn't there paragraph gap too?