# How do I get rid of the white space around included graphics?

Tags: graphics, pdf, crop

I know that my question may be a duplicate, but I couldn't find a solution that worked for me elsewhere on the site.

Here is the MWE :

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
This is my attempt to import the image into latex.
I do not know how so I decided to try all possible cases. 
\begin{center}
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[scale=0.7]{12.pdf}
\end{figure}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

You can get my `12.pdf` file there: [12.pdf](https://www.mediafire.com/?2xvz49z487hxg57).

After compiling, I get a PDF file with a page that contains my text, and another contains the image in `12.pdf`. The problem is that I want to insert the image right after the words, but there seems to be lot of white space (in the image).

So, how can I get rid of that white space? I'm not a professional TeX user, so the simpler the solution, the better.

Comment: Very likely, you can mitigate the effect by cropping correctly the picture (use tools like pdfcrop, GIMP or whatever), even if I would draw my self the two triangles. TikZ, PSTricks are candidates for drawing.

Comment: Side note: Instead of `\begin{center}
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[scale=0.7]{12.pdf}
\end{figure}
\end{center}`, write `\begin{figure} \centering
\includegraphics[scale=0.7]{12.pdf}
\end{figure}`.

Comment: As Claudio has pointed out, this is only related to your image. The image itself takes up a hole page, including all the blank space. Crop it correctly and then latex will position it correctly automatically.

Comment: The problem is: How can I crop? This is only a simple example, there are the others images that is more complicated so I do not use TikZ or PSTricks. I also do not know how to use GIMP, pdfcrop. And as I said above, I am not a professional user, so please explain for me in the most precise way.
Best,
Nguyễn Duy Khánh

Comment: I think this is what you want. [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/2en40resotb1hcd/12.PDF). You have to tell us what system you are using like mac or pc. I did most of these pdf figures for my advisor.

Comment: @Aung : I use Window 8

Comment: But how can I crop by pdfcrop? Is there any command that can used for the whole latex file? I really do not want to use GIMP, which is too complicated for me.

Comment: I usually use texshop to crop but it is only for mac. Do you have Adobe Acrobat or Inkscape ?

Comment: Is there any other ways? Like a latex code that can help me to crop? I have heard about the pdfcrop package.

Comment: @Nguyễn Duy Khánh: In case you work on a windows system, here is  solution: copy these lines in a .batch file (call it e.g. mycrop.bat, or whatever you want, but *not* pdfcrop.bat):  `@echo off
echo "Cropping pdf files ..."
for %%i in (./*.pdf) do pdfcrop %%i  %%~ni-cropped.pdf --verbose
echo.
echo Done 
pause`

Comment: @Nguyễn Duy Khánh: Didn't have the time to finish writing. Here is the end: You put the .bat in a directory containing your pdf's and it will crop all of them, adding `-cropped`at the end of its name.

Answer (score 4):

With respect to the problem, first consider that the `figure` environment is a `float`, that mean that it can stay here, or float freely to the top, to the bottom, or jump to the next  page or the last page, according to complex rules. See [What are penalties and which ones are defined?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/51263/what-are-penalties-and-which-ones-are-defined) and [How to influence the position of float environments like figure and table in LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39017/how-to-influence-the-position-of-float-environments-like-figure-and-table-in-lat)

Moreover, a float can add some vertical space around it. See [Space after float with [h]](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24454/space-after-float-with-h)

But the float width is always the width of the text, so center it is completely useless. As Jubobs point, what you really want is  center the contents of the float, but `center` add vertical space also, so it is better `\centering`.

Another problem could be the  `\includegraphic` option. Play only with the text and this command in your MWE, to isolate the problem.

Note that you fix a size **relative of the original file size**  (that is, the 70%  of who know ...) so if the image can be fitted or not depend of the original file.

To avoid this, usually it is a better idea fix an absolute  `width` or `height` size  (as `[height=10cm]`) that you know that is smaller than the page, but much better approach is to fix sizes **relatives  to the text size area**. For example, with `[height=.5\textheight]` so your image will be the half of the text, no matter if you are using an A4 or an A5 paper, or how wider are your margins.  You can fix both `width` or `height` and maintain the aspect ratio in this way:

```
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=.95\textheight,keepaspectratio]
{example-image-10x16} % require the mwe package
```

[image: MWE0]

What now? The image can be fitted in the page, filling the remaining space. But note that is too close to the text. To take care of this,  you can include  this image in a float (or for another reason, as include a caption), but obviously reducing `.95\textheight` value as needed, if you want avoid a float jump:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}

This is my attempt to import the image into latex.
I do not know how so I decided to try all possible cases. 

\begin{figure}[h]
\centering 
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=.75\textheight,keepaspectratio]{example-image-10x16}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image: MWE]

Finally, if the problem is not a proper scaling, but a bad image that contain empty areas, you can crop the image with Gimp or another tool, as suggested in the comments, but also maintain the original image and show only some area. For example:

```
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=.75\textheight,
keepaspectratio,bb=0bp 0bp 200bp 300bp,clip]{example-image-10x16}
```

[image: MWE2]

Note: For a MWE with example images, use the option `demo` in `graphicx` package or install the `mwe` package to use some standard images as `example-image-a`, so others can deal with your code without downloading any image (May be you will need include `\usepackage{mwe}` in the preamble to use the example images, but at least in Linux with TeXLive 2013 is not needed.)