# white space after figures

Tags: spacing

I tried to remove the white space after figure using \setlength\belowcaptionskip{-10pt} but it didn't work. any help?

```
\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.8\linewidth]{figure/example-product.PNG}
\setlength\belowcaptionskip{-10pt}
\caption{Future plan for CAT ‘environment’}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Probably, your image would require cropping. Put it in a `\fbox`, you'll see at once if it's  the case.

Answer (score 4):

To remove all the space below the figure, you can use `\setlength\intextsep{0pt}`. This will have to be used outside the float, therefore I put it within curlybraces `{}` so that it would only be a local change. Put it in the preamble if you want it to affect all figures.

Even though this might solve this issue, as Werner points out, this will not always work depending on where the picture is placed. Therefore, see his answer in [Space after float with [h]](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/24468/89976)

**Output**

[image]

**Code**

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
{\setlength\intextsep{0pt}
\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.8\linewidth]{example-image-a}
\caption{Future plan for CAT ‘environment’}
\end{figure}
}%
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is not entirely complete... see (possible duplicate) [Space after float with `[h]`](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/24454/5764).

Comment: If the float does not stay `[h]`ere, there's no guarantee that the use of `\intextsep` would be used.